# Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I am grabbing data from my product table. I cant seem to figure it out what the error.

## Product

```
<?php       
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="tianen"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="product";

$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","tianen");

$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM product");

echo"$result";

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Problem

You can't echo `$result` because it's not a string. [**It's a `mysqli_result` object. That's what `mysqli_query` returns if your query works**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

You can't `echo` an object in PHP, unless it has a [**`__toString` magic method**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring). [**The `mysqli_result` object has no such method**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php), so it can't be `echo`ed. Thus, the error.

## The Solution

What you *want* to do is loop over the results using [**one of the `fetch_*` methods or functions**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php), such as [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php). The documentation contains examples, and there are plenty of good tutorials about using MySQLi out there.

Here's an example using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`:

```
<?php       
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="tianen"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="product";

$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","tianen");

$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM product");

if ($result) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        // do things with $row, an associative array with keys matching your table's column names
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

mysqli_query will return an object that you then have to extract rows from. Once you have rows you can then access fields from each row.

The way I do this is by looping through the mysqli result (I'm not sure if there's another way):

```
// Create an empty array to store rows
$rows = [];

// The fetch_assoc function will automatically generate an iterator to return false when there are no more rows to fetch.
// Each result will be a row in the form of an associative array
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($con, $result)) {
    array_push($rows, $row);
}
```

There's also another way to use mysqli as objects, which I find easier as 1. the function names are shorter and 2. you don't have to keep passing in $con parameters. instead you would say `$result = $con->query("SELECT ...");`